# KeyError on adjacency list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, keyerror

Getting a KeyError and can't figure out why.

I'm importing data from an excel sheet using pandas and using it to create a graph using an adjacency list. The data imports fine, but when using the add_edge function I created I keep getting a KeyError.

Link to a sample of the dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/80v3dhdf0c0o7cs/London%20Underground%20data%20fixed%20copy2.csv?dl=0

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2xfa.png)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'my_file_path.xlsx')

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes): 
        self.nodes = nodes  #all nodes in graph
        self.adj_list = {}  #adjacency list

        #loops through nodes, and removes duplicates using sets, then adds result as key of adjacency list
        self.adj_list = {node: set() for node in self.nodes}
   
   
    def add_edge(self, node_1, node_2, weight):
        #adds node2 to the location of node1
        
        #adds node_2 and the corresponding weight to the location of node_1
        self.adj_list[node_1].add((node_2, weight))
        #adds node_1 and the corresponding weight to the location of node_1
        self.adj_list[node_2].add((node_1, weight))

    #prints graph in readable format
    def print_graph(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            print(node, ":", self.adj_list[node])



nodes = []

for index, row, in df.iterrows():
    station_a = row['Station A']
    nodes.append(station_a)


graph = Graph(nodes)

for index, row, in df.iterrows():
  
    station_a = row['Station A']
    station_b = row['Station B']
    weight = row['Weight']
    graph.add_edge(station_a, station_b, weight)

graph.print_graph()
```

Comment: Probably it should be `self.adj_list[node_2].add((node_1, weight))` ? Are you sure that all stations in StationB column are also present in StationA column, is Grange Hill in StationA? Also it's impossible to run your example. Maybe you want to have your data in CSV and publish link to it?

Comment: That line of code is as you suggested. Sorry about that. I also amended the error in the post. I've checked and they are present, I'll upload it as a CSV format now. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I can't add CSV files to provide an example.

Comment: you can put a link to Dropbox

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide the complete traceback. Also, provide a sample of your CSV file in a code block. We don't want the entire dataset, just enough to help you debug.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, Thank you very much for the welcome, I'll be sure to look at all the links provided and amend the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The last station in a line (Like Elephant & Castle) is not on Station A column that you use to create your dictionary, and it should be in your dictionary (nodes). That is why you get the error.

you could change to this:

```
for index, row, in df.iterrows():
    station_a = row['Station A']
    station_b = row['Station B']
    nodes.append(station_a)
    nodes.append(station_b)
nodes=list(set(nodes))
```